# MVC Web API 2 OAuth OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext Always Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I am trying to do OAuth with Google on an MVC Web API 2 project. Whenever I call the GetExternalLogin API Method I keep getting this: `error: invalid_request`.

I have everything setup on the google site correctly as I tested the same configuration with another MVC application and it worked perfectly.

I have made no changes to the code generated other than putting in the `app.UseGoogleAuthentication` with the ClientId and ClientSecret.

Regardless here is my ConfigureAuth:

```
// Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
   app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
   app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

// Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
// and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
   app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

// Configure the application for OAuth based flow
   PublicClientId = "self";
   OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
   {
       TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
       Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
       AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
       AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
       // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
       AllowInsecureHttp = true
   };


   OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
   OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat = OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat;

// Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
   app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

// Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //    consumerKey: "",
        //    consumerSecret: "");


   app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
   {
       ClientId = "My Key",
       ClientSecret = "Secret"
   });
```

When I go through and debug I get to the `ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs` class and the `ValidateClientRedirectUri` method which is turning out to be the problem.

The method looks like so:

```
public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
{
    if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
    {
        context.Validated();

        Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

        if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);

}
```

When I put a break point entering the method I notice that everything in the context is null. So every time the context.ClientId will also be null and then I get the `error: invalid_request` message.

I read that it was because context.IsValid is set to false so I tried to call `context.Validated();` as the first thing in the method and then just returning `return Task.FromResult<object>(null);`. However, that did not work as even when I call `context.Validated()` the context does not change IsValid to true is stays false.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Facing the same issue now. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not really. I found a work around, which is basically just use the JS API provided by the OAuth provider. Since I use Google and Facebook in my app I just used their JS library.

You can find the FB JS SDK here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript

and the google one here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

Hope that helps!